# How to system-widely configure kdesu to use sudo instead of su (KDE Plasma)?

Tags: sudo, kde, su, plasma

I'm trying to make `kdesu` use `sudo` instead of `su`. I know that this is possible to achieve by creating a local `kdesurc` file by running `kwriteconfig5 --file kdesurc --group super-user-command --key super-user-command sudo`. The problem is that this only applies to the current user. I want to change `kdesu` configuration system-widely. Is there a system-wide `kdesurc` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/xdg` is the global location directory for these settings (not perfectly intuitive, indeed...). You can try there, it should work.